# How to extract data from html table in shell script?

Tags: html, regex, shell, sed, html-parsing

I am trying to create a BASH script what would extract the data from HTML table. 
Below is the example of table from where I need to extract data:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td><b>Component</b></td>
<td><b>Status</b></td>
<td><b>Time / Error</b></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>SAVE_DOCUMENT</td><td>OK</td><td>0.406 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>GET_DOCUMENT</td><td>OK</td><td>0.332 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>DVK_SEND</td><td>OK</td><td>0.001 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>DVK_RECEIVE</td><td>OK</td><td>0.001 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>GET_USER_INFO</td><td>OK</td><td>0.143 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>NOTIFICATIONS</td><td>OK</td><td>0.001 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>ERROR_LOG</td><td>OK</td><td>0.001 s</td></tr>
<tr><td>SUMMARY_STATUS</td><td>OK</td><td>0.888 s</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I want the BASH script to output it like so:

```
SAVE_DOCUMENT OK 0.475 s
GET_DOCUMENT OK 0.345 s
DVK_SEND OK 0.002 s
DVK_RECEIVE OK 0.001 s
GET_USER_INFO OK 4.465 s
NOTIFICATIONS OK 0.001 s
ERROR_LOG OK 0.002 s
SUMMARY_STATUS OK 5.294 s
```

How to do it?

So far I have tried using the sed, but I don't know how to use it quite well. The header of the table(Component, Status, Time/Error) I excluded with grep using `grep "<tr><td>`, so only lines starting with `<tr><td>` will be selected for next parsing (sed).
This is what I used: `sed 's@<\([^<>][^<>]*\)>\([^<>]*\)</\1>@\2@g'`
But then `<tr>` tags still remain and also it wont separate the strings. In other words the result of this script is:

```
<tr>SAVE_DOCUMENTOK0.406 s</tr>
```

The full command of the script I'm working on is:

```
cat $FILENAME | grep "<tr><td>" | sed 's@<\([^<>][^<>]*\)>\([^<>]*\)</\1>@\2@g'
```

Comment: Does it have to be a bash script? If you are on Linux, perhaps a Perl script would be an easier option.  You could then use the [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.68/Parser.pm) module, or similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go with `(g)awk`, it's capable :-), here is a solution, but *please note*: it's only working with the exact html table format you had posted.

```
 awk -F "</*td>|</*tr>" '/<\/*t[rd]>.*[A-Z][A-Z]/ {print $3, $5, $7 }' FILE
```

Here you can see it in action: https://ideone.com/zGfLe

Some explanation:

1. `-F` sets the input field separator to a regexp (any of `tr`'s or `td`'s opening or closing tag
2. then works only on lines that matches those tags AND at least two upercasse fields
3. then prints the needed fields.

HTH

Comment: Superb explanation! Thank you a lot!

Comment: How to edit output more? For example if I want the output to be like this: SAVE_DOCUMENT="OK 0.475 s"
GET_DOCUMENT="OK 0.345 s"
DVK_SEND="OK 0.002 s"

Comment: Just replace the `{print $3, $5, $7 }` part with `{print $3 "=\"" $5, $7 "\"" }`
HTH

Comment: Yeah, it works! One more question, how to remove space and "s" behind the numbers, so the output would be: DVK_SEND="OK 0.002"

Comment: It's a very little bit trickier: use `{print $3 "=\"" $5, gensub(" *s$","","g",$7) "\"" }`
HTH

Answer (score 12):

You can use bash `xpath` (**XML::XPath** perl module) to accomplish that task very easily:

```
xpath -e '//tr[position()>1]' test_input1.xml 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/<\/*tr>//g' -e 's/<td>//g' -e 's/<\/td>/ /g'
```

Answer (score 10):

You may use `html2text` command and format the columns via `column`, e.g.:

```
$ html2text table.html | column -ts'|'

Component                                      Status  Time / Error
SAVE_DOCUMENT                                           OK            0.406 s     
GET_DOCUMENT                                            OK            0.332 s     
DVK_SEND                                                OK            0.001 s     
DVK_RECEIVE                                             OK            0.001 s     
GET_USER_INFO                                           OK            0.143 s     
NOTIFICATIONS                                           OK            0.001 s     
ERROR_LOG                                               OK            0.001 s     
SUMMARY_STATUS                                          OK            0.888 s
```

then parse it further from there (e.g. `cut`, `awk`, `ex`).

In case you'd like to sort it first, you can use `ex`, see the example [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10289/467) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148874/21471).

Comment: Unfortunately, `html2text` peppers its output with backspace characters by default, so even though your output _looks_ OK, it its full of hidden `\b` (backspace) sequences. Safely removing them requires more work (using `-nobs` is not an option, because it surfaces hidden `_` instances used for padding that are then hard to distinguish from `_` instances in the _data_).

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways of doing this but here's one:

```
grep '^<tr><td>' < $FILENAME \
| sed \
    -e 's:<tr>::g'  \
    -e 's:</tr>::g' \
    -e 's:</td>::g' \
    -e 's:<td>: :g' \
| cut -c2-
```

You could use more **sed(1)** (`-e 's:^ ::'`) instead of the `cut -c2-` to remove the leading space but **cut(1)** doesn't get as much love as it deserves. And the backslashes are just there for formatting, you can remove them to get a one liner or leave them in and make sure that they're immediately followed by a newline.

The basic strategy is to slowly pull the HTML apart piece by piece rather than trying to do it all at once with a single incomprehensible pile of regex syntax.

Parsing HTML with a shell pipeline isn't the best idea ever but you can do it if the HTML is known to come in a very specific format. If there will be variation then you'd be better with with a real HTML parser in Perl, Ruby, Python, or even C.

Comment: Thank you too! Also very good explanation, but Zsolt Botykai solution looks cooler:)

Comment: @Marko: Yeah, awk is a better tool for this sort of thing, more consistent regex handling than sed too.

Answer (score 4):

A solution based on multi-platform web-scraping CLI **[`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads)** and **[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)**:
<sup>Tip of the hat to [Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703456/reino) for providing the simpler XPath equivalent to the original [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) solution.[1]</sup>

```
xidel -s -e '//tr[position() > 1]/join(td)' file
```

With the sample input, this yields:

```
SAVE_DOCUMENT OK 0.406 s
GET_DOCUMENT OK 0.332 s
DVK_SEND OK 0.001 s
DVK_RECEIVE OK 0.001 s
GET_USER_INFO OK 0.143 s
NOTIFICATIONS OK 0.001 s
ERROR_LOG OK 0.001 s
SUMMARY_STATUS OK 0.888 s
```

Explanation:

- `//tr[position() > 1]` matches the `tr` elements starting with the 2nd one, so as to skip the header row), and `join(td)` joins the values of the matching elements' child `td` elements with an implied single space as the separator.
- `-s` makes `xidel` silent (suppresses output of status information).

---

While **[`html2text`](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/) is convenient for *display*** of the extracted data, **providing machine-parseable output is non-trivial**, unfortunately:

```
html2text file | awk -F' *\\|' 'NR>2 {gsub(/^\||.\b/, ""); $1=$1; print}'
```

The Awk command removes the hidden `\b`-based (backspace-based) sequences that `html2text` outputs by default, and parses the lines into fields by `|`, and then outputs them with a space as the separator (a space is Awk's default output field separator; to change it to a tab, for instance, use `-v OFS='\t'`).

<sup>Note: Use of `-nobs` to suppress backspace sequences at the source is *not* an option, because you then won't be able to distinguish between the hidden-by-default `_` instances used for padding and actual `_` characters in the data.</sup>

Note: Given that `html2text` seemingly invariably uses `|` as the column separator, **the above will only work robustly if the are no `|` instances in the *data* being extracted**.

---

<sup>[1] `xidel -s --xquery 'for $tr in //tr[position()>1] return join($tr/td, " ")' file`</sup>

Comment: That's a great simplification, @Reino, thanks - I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, pandoc does a good job when you have extracted the HTML table. For example,

```
pandoc --from html --to plain table.txt
  ---------------- -------- --------------
  Component        Status   Time / Error
  SAVE_DOCUMENT    OK       0.406 s
  GET_DOCUMENT     OK       0.332 s
  DVK_SEND         OK       0.001 s
  DVK_RECEIVE      OK       0.001 s
  GET_USER_INFO    OK       0.143 s
  NOTIFICATIONS    OK       0.001 s
  ERROR_LOG        OK       0.001 s
  SUMMARY_STATUS   OK       0.888 s
  ---------------- -------- --------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file using [Ex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) (part of Vim) by removing HTML tags, e.g.:

```
$ ex -s +'%s/<[^>]\+>/ /g' +'v/0/d' +'wq! /dev/stdout' table.html 
  SAVE_DOCUMENT  OK  0.406 s  
  GET_DOCUMENT  OK  0.332 s  
  DVK_SEND  OK  0.001 s  
  DVK_RECEIVE  OK  0.001 s  
  GET_USER_INFO  OK  0.143 s  
  NOTIFICATIONS  OK  0.001 s  
  ERROR_LOG  OK  0.001 s  
  SUMMARY_STATUS  OK  0.888 s
```

Here is shorter version by printing the whole file without HTML tags:

```
$ ex +'%s/<[^>]\+>/ /g|%p' -scq! table.html
```

Explanation:

- `%s/<[^>]\+>/ /g` - **S**ubstitute all HTML tags into empty space.
- `v/0/d` - **D**eletes all lines without `0`.
- `wq! /dev/stdout` - **Q**uits editor and **w**rites the buffer to the standard output.