# sed to remove content between two patterns

Tags: regex, bash, text, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract data from HTML table with BASH script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854586/extract-data-from-html-table-with-bash-script)

I have an html file that contains the following content. I want to use sed to remove all the content (multiline) between the patterns `< script ..... >` and `</script>` and leave the rest as it is. I also want to remove the tags.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!
I tried both of the following but with no luck.

```
cat test.html | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/< script.*<\/script>//g' > output.txt
```

and

```
sed '/< script/,/<\/script>/d' test.html > output.txt
```

---

```
don't touch this.

this is not to be removed < script bla bla> this is to be

removed. < /script> this is going to

stay < script bla bla bla bla bla> remove this

and this 

and this < /script> and this stays as is.

this too.
```

---

Comment: Could both `<script>` and `</script>` appear in the same line?

Comment: apparently second most popular question on stackoverflow - "how to remove .. sed .. between two patterns?" :)
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sed+patterns

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
cat yourfile | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's,< script.*< /script>,,g'
```

Note the space in ending tag

Comment: Useless use of `cat` (`tr -d '\n' yourfile`). And you are using a greedy regex, so it can delete something you might want to leave untouched. And see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11621

Comment: `cat` (or tr < yourfile) seems necessary with certain version of tr like tr (GNU coreutils) 8.9

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};/\x00/q1;s/<\s*\/\?script[^>]*>/\x00/g;s/\x00[^\x00]*\x00//g' file
```

There is a vague chance it might fail because the HTML file contains the  hexcode `\x00` in which case the return code will be `1` and the file output will be unchanged.

Explanation:

- `:a;$!{N;ba}` slurp the file into the pattern space
- `/\x00/q1` check the file for hexcode `\x00` and if found quit with return code of `1`
- `s/<\s*\/\?script[^>]*>/\x00/g` replace all `script` start and end tags with `\x00`
- `s/\x00[^\x00]*\x00//g` remove everything between `\x00`'s