# Extract content between html tags <pre> using bash shell command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I want to parse the below html text string using shell script in bash.

```
    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter-2</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter-1</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter0</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter1</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter2</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter3</pre>\n                                    <pre style=\"font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 0;\">peter4</pre>\n
```

Expected output:

```
peter-2
peter-1
peter0
peter1
peter2
peter3
peter4
```

I want the shell command to extract values based on `<pre` tag and not based on position.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I dont want to use direct commands. I would like to use regex so that I dont have to install any command.

Comment: `<pre\s.*?>(.*?)<\/pre>` https://regex101.com/r/sfanee/1. you can use command like `grep -po "<pre\s.*?>(.*?)<\/pre>"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse HTML using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358698/parse-html-using-shell)

Comment: @mjrezaee did you test the grep? I run it and it does not work. grep command fails. what operating system did you run it? it seems to select the correct fields on regex101

Comment: wrt `I would like to use regex so that I dont have to install any command` - a regexp is nothing but a string of characters without a command to do something with it so it's not clear what you meant by that statement. Btw regex101 is practically useless for anything involving command line tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input is always that regular and you can't use an XML parser for some reason and just want something cheap and cheerful then with a sed that accepts `\n` in the replacement text (e.g. GNU sed):

```
$ sed 's:</pre>:\n:g' file | sed -n 's/.*>//p'
peter-2
peter-1
peter0
peter1
peter2
peter3
peter4
```

Otherwise in bash with any sed:

```
$ sed 's:</pre>:\'$'\n'':g' file | sed -n 's/.*>//p'
peter-2
peter-1
peter0
peter1
peter2
peter3
peter4
```

or any awk in any shell:

```
$ awk '{gsub("</pre>","\n")}1' file | awk 'sub(/.*>/,"")'
peter-2
peter-1
peter0
peter1
peter2
peter3
peter4
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks @Ed Morton

Answer (score 0):

```
# xml_read function
# usage: xml_read <filename> <attribute> [<tag>] (default is </string>)
xml_read () {
  local filename="${1//\*/.\*}" attribute="${2//\*/.\*}" tag="${3//\*/.\*}" value
  [ -n "${tag}" ] || tag=string
  [ -n "${filename}" ] && [ -n "${attribute}" ] && \
  value="$(grep -iwhoIrm1 "<${tag} name=\"${attribute}\">.*</${tag}>" "${filename}" 2> /dev/null | cut -d\> -f2)"
  [ -n "${value}" ] && while [ "${value:(-1)}" != "<" ]; do value="${value%?}"; done
  printf '%s' "${value%?}"
}
```

edit:

not sure about your input format `\n` is linefeed? `cut` works line based i have added a `sed` to modify the input file into readable format

your xml file looks different from mine. the ported function could look like this

```
#!bin/bash

# xml_read function
# usage: xml_read <filename> <attribute> [<tag>] (default is </string>)
xml_read () {
  local filename="${1//\*/.\*}" attribute="${2//\*/.\*}" tag="${3//\*/.\*}" value
  [ -n "${tag}" ] || tag=string
  [ -n "${filename}" ] && [ -n "${attribute}" ] && \
  grep -iwhoI "<${tag} ${attribute}=.*>.*</${tag}>" "${filename}" 2> /dev/null | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1
}

# evaluate linefeeds
sed -i 's,\\n,'\\n',g' test.xml

# call function
xml_read test.xml style pre
```

Comment: attribute = style, tag = pre (attribute accept asterisk wildcard like \*style)